# How to get the text of hidden check boxes inside a scroll bar using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, hidden

I'm trying to automate Filter By Brand scenario in [BigBasket](http://www.bigbasket.com/) and now stuck up in a situation where my code could not print the brand names that are hidden inside a scroll bar.

Steps to follow

1. Go to [www.bigbasket.com](http://www.bigbasket.com/)
2. Click Skip & Explore button
3. Search Apple and view the list of brands on the left side

   > @FindAll({@FindBy(xpath="//*@id='filter_brands_list']/div/div[1](http://www.bigbasket.com/)/li/label")})
   >
   > List chkBrands;

The above lines of code identifies all the brand names but when I print them using the below code I can see only the brand names that are visible

```
for(WebElement eachElement:chkBrands){
    System.out.println("No. of brands is "+chkBrands.size());
    System.out.println(eachElement.getText());
}
```

Could you please let me know the solution? I apologize that I could not think of a solution as I'm an amateur in Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebElement.getText()` will return the text of the element only if it is displayed on the screen.

Meaning if the `isDisplayed` method returns `false` then `getText()`method will return empty.

[Explanation with Examples Here](http://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/)

> As defined in WebDriver spec, Selenium WebDriver will only interact
>   with visible elements, therefore the text of an invisible element will
>   always be returned as an empty string.
>
> However, in some cases, one may find it useful to get the hidden text,
>   which can be retrieved from element's textContent, innerText or
>   innerHTML attribute, by calling element.attribute('attributeName') or
>   injecting JavaScript like return arguments[0].attributeName.

So you can get the text by `textContent` attribute

```
eachElement.getAttribute("textContent")
```

Comment: Hi Madhan, Thanks for your reply. That worked for me.

Comment: @SrinivasanRamu Then you can [accept it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your_xpath"));
String text_value = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;",element);
```